# Building a query using NOT EXISTS in jpa criteria api

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have two tables named as table1 ,table2.Both the tables are having same no  of fields.There is no relation between these two tables.My requirement is I want all the records in table1 which are not there in table2. So I have written a query using Criteria API. But it is not giving the correct result. As I am new to this JPA and criteria API, can any one point me where I am doing wrong.The below code I am using to do this.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = mediationEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Table1>  cq = cb.createQuery(Table1.class);
Root<Table1> table1 = cq.from(Table1.class);
cq.select(table1)

Subquery<Table2> subquery =  cq.subquery(Table2.class)
Root table2 = subquery.from(Table2.class)
subquery.select(table2)
cq.where(cb.not(cb.exists(subquery)))
TypedQuery<Table1> typedQuery = mediationEntityManager.createQuery(cq); 
List<Table1> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

MySQL Query :

```sql
SELECT table1 
FROM   table1 table1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT table2 
                   FROM   table2 table2 
                   WHERE  table2.name = table1.name 
                          AND table2.education = table1.education 
                          AND table2.age = table1.age) 
       AND table1.name = 'san' 
       AND table1.age = '10';
```

I need the JPA criteria API query for the above mentioned MySQL query.

Comment: But how are you differentiating the data between these tables, specify criteria/column etc

Comment: Hi very thanks for giving the reply i am giving the actual mysql query in my original Question.Plz look into it and if possible give me the jpa criteria api query for same mysql query.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try the below code with Criteria API. I haven't tried, but you can try modifying the code accordingly.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = mediationEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();  
CriteriaQuery<Table1> query = cb.createQuery(Table1.class); 
Root<Table1> table1 =  query.from(Table1.class); 
query.select(table1);
//--  
Subquery<Table2> subquery = query.subquery(Table2.class); 
Root<Table2> table2 = subquery.from(Table2.class);  
subquery.select(table2);  
//--
List<Predicate> subQueryPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>(); 
subQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(table1.get(Table1_.name), table2.get(Table2_.name)));
subQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(table1.get(Table1_.age), table2.get(Table2_.age)));
subQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(table1.get(Table1_.education), table2.get(Table2_.education)));
subquery.where(subQueryPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})); 
//--
List<Predicate> mainQueryPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>(); 
mainQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(table1.get(Table1_.name), "san");
mainQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(table1.get(Table1_.age), "10");
mainQueryPredicates.add(cb.not(cb.exists(subquery))); 
//--
query.where(mainQueryPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})); 
TypedQuery<Table1> typedQuery =  mediationEntityManager.createQuery(query); 
List<Table1> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Also, you can try below JPQL query, which is easier to understand, alter & debug.

```sql
SELECT t1 
FROM   table1 t1, 
       table2 t2 
WHERE  t1.name = 'san' 
       AND t1.age = '10' 
       AND (t2.name <> t1.name 
             AND t2.education <> t1.education 
             AND t2.age <> t1.age);
```

Comment: I prefered criteria Api bcoz that is my requirement.

Comment: Hi, How can i pass the table name as dynamic to the create Query method.

Comment: @aaaa You can try `createQuery()`, no need to mention class. Also, you can drop generics(I don't prefer) & can add conditions to fetch required result, casting objects to required class explicitly

Comment: Ok.But i need to mention in from clause also that dynamic value.I want to make my query as totally dynamic.Bcoz when i run my application i dont know from which table it will fetch the data.If you have any samples can you give me.Sorry for my poor English.Really appreciate you help.Thank You.

Comment: @aaaa It's difficult to reply so many queries at once. You could post it as a new question

Comment: I have posted a new question.Can you plz look into it.