# Spring-Data JPA: How to make a jpa criteria query

Tags: criteria-api, spring-data-jpa

Given this two entities:

```
post         post_category
  - id         - post_id
  - title      - name
  - text
```

I'd like to make this query using jpa criteria query:

```
select * from post
where post.id in (
  select post_id from post_category
  where name = '<category1>' and name = '<category2>' ... and name = '<categoryN>')
```

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ about what sort of questions are ok on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. At present this question is to open ended - we're not up for writing code for your.

Comment: Similar one here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13912967/366964 with some changes for quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query sketch I think it will not return any results. I have changed it to mean `name in ('<category1>','<category2>', ...)` instead. Which may not match your case.

This assumes that you have your mapping set up properly on your classes for JPA to work. For example

```
    class PostCategory {
        private String name;
        private Post post;
        ...
        @ManyToOne
        public Post getPost() {
            return post;
        }
        ...
```

In which case your DAO code would resemble this (given a List nameValues object)

```
    // Set up the subquery
    DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(PostCategory.class)
        .setProjection(Projections.property("post.id"))
        .add(Restrictions.in("name", nameValues));

    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Post.class)
        .add(Subqueries.eqProperty("id", dc));
```

But if you want a list of Post objects which have ALL of the categories then you will need to make a separate DetachedCriteria instance for each category and add each as an AND'ed Subquery.