# JPA Criteria API NOT IN Code Simplification and Optimization

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I am new to JPA Criteria API.

2 Questions:

1. How can I further simplify this method, 3rd and 4th statements both needed the class parameter?
2. How can I translate the `NOT IN` operation to `NOT EXISTS` to improve performance?

   ```
   public List<Pilot> getPilotsExcept(final Integer... entityIds) {

     final CriteriaBuilder critBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

     final CriteriaQuery<Pilot> critQuery =
           critBuilder.createQuery(getEntityClass());

     final Root<Pilot> root = critQuery.from(getEntityClass());  // Why pass the class again?
   critQuery.select(root).where(
       critBuilder.not(root.get("id").in(Arrays.asList(entityIds))));

     final TypedQuery<Pilot> typedQuery = em.createQuery(critQuery);
     return typedQuery.getResultList();
   }
   ```

Comment: Maybe duplicate with
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859780/building-a-query-using-not-exists-in-jpa-criteria-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why pass the class again?

In Criteria API query components are represented by objects. So `select` clause and the `from` clause are represented by objects:

- The `select` clause is represented as follows:

  ```
  CriteriaQuery<Pilot> critQuery = critBuilder.createQuery(getEntityClass());
  ```

  The `Pilot` class in the above line represents the return type of the query result.
- And on the other hand the `from` clause of the query is defined as follows:

  ```
  final Root<Pilot> root = critQuery.from(getEntityClass());
  ```

In this example, both the `Root` and `CriteriaQuery` happen to have the same type. But this is not the case for all queries. In some queries you might want to return one or more attributes from the query (but not all attribute of the entities involved in a query). In those cases, the type you specify in the `CriteriaQuery` will be different from the one you use in the `Root`. For example, let us say you have a `name` attribute in your `Pilot` entity and you are only interested in the list of names of the `Pilot` entities. In this case, your `CriteriaQuery` will be defined as follows:

```
    CrtieriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);
```

But the definition of the `Root` does not change, in your example.

> NOT EXISTS expression

To be able to convert your `not in` expresion to `not exists` form you have to formulate a subquery using the ids. Here is an extract from the JPA specification:

> An EXISTS expression is a predicate that is true only if the result of the subquery consists of one ormore values and that is false otherwise.
>   The syntax of an exists expression is
>
> exists_expression::= [NOT] EXISTS (subquery)
>   Of course, this must be translated to the Criteria API, in which case the syntax will be
>
> not(exists(subquery)).

Here is an example for creating a subquery (pseudo code):

```
Subquery<Integer> sq = critQuery.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<Pilot> pilot = sq.from(Pilot.class);
sq.select(pilot.<Integer>get("id"));
sq.where(<some_condition>);
```

Comment: You explained both points very well.  I did notice that  the code deletes everything during testing and I was able to correct it, I am now confident I will be able to translate the code to `not exists` based on your explanation. Thank you for the comprehensive answer.